# Strtok_r segmentation fault

Tags: c

I know this has been asked before, but previous answers have said you can't modify a string literal, and unless I am misunderstanding I am not. I can sucesfully use strtok_r until the very last line of input, then I get a seg fault. Why would this happen? Heres a simplified version of my code. From printing I know it processes through get b, but then there is a seg fault?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>   //strlen
#include <stdlib.h>

    void handler(char * input){
    char * end_str;
    char * token =strtok_r(input, "\n", &end_str);
    char * endd_str;
    char * token2= strtok_r(token, " ", &endd_str);
    while(token!=0){
        printf("%s\n",token);
        token=strtok_r(NULL,"\n",&end_str);
        while(token2 !=0){
            token2 =strtok_r(NULL," ",&endd_str);
            printf("%s\n",token2);}
    }

}

int main(int argc , char *argv[])
{
    char test[100]="set a,10.5\nset b,11.5\nget b\nadd e,a,b\nsub g,a,b";
    handler(test);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Does the code provided also fail?  If not, you have not provided enough data for anyone to tell you why it fails.  See http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Cannot recreate the seg fault with the sample code you have provided. Are you sure it is `strtok_r` that's causing the seg fault and not something else.

Comment: Why do you think the program execution will result in something meaningful? You can view generated binary code to see what happens in your case.

Answer (score 2):

You're interleaving `strtok_r` calls working off of the same string.  On the second iteration of the inner `while` loop, before the call to `token2 =strtok_r(NULL," ",&endd_str);`, `endd_str` points to an empty string because the string it was matching against reached the end, so `strtok_r` returns `NULL`.  Passing that `NULL` to `printf` causes the segfault.

After each parse of the `"\n"` delimiter, do a fresh start of looping through the `" "` delimeter.  Don't do the outer one again until you've exhausted the inner one.  Also, move your `strtok_r` calls to the end of the loop so the `while` condition checks them properly.

You need to do the following:

```
void handler(char * input){
    char * end_str;
    char * token =strtok_r(input, "\n", &end_str);
    while(token!=0){
        printf("%s\n",token);
        char * endd_str;
        char * token2= strtok_r(token, " ", &endd_str);
        while(token2 !=0){
            printf("%s\n",token2);
            token2 =strtok_r(NULL," ",&endd_str);    // call at end of loop
        }
        token=strtok_r(NULL,"\n",&end_str);          // call at end of loop
    }
}
```

Ouput:

```
set a,10.5
set
a,10.5
set b,11.5
set
b,11.5
get b
get
b
add e,a,b
add
e,a,b
sub g,a,b
sub
g,a,b
```

Answer (score 1):

Works perfectly for me (MS Visual C++). Only difference is usage `strtok_s` instead of `strtok_r` considering it is Windows instead of POSIX.

Here I have added some modifications to your code.

```
#include <string.h>   //strlen
#include <stdlib.h>

void handler(char * input){
    char * end_str;
    char * token =strtok_s(input, "\n", &end_str); // tokenize input string
    char * endd_str;
    char * token2 = NULL;

    while(token!=0){

        printf("%s\n",token);

        token2 = strtok_s(token, " ", &endd_str); // retokenize first token
        while(token2 !=0){
            printf("%s\n",token2); // replace printf call to avoid null string output and first token miss
            token2 =strtok_s(NULL," ",&endd_str);}

        token = end_str; // "important" restore char pointer to point the last untokenized input character

        token=strtok_s(token,"\n",&end_str); // the same as printf issue is for all loops body
    }

}

int main(int argc , char *argv[])
{
    char test[100]="set a,10.5\nset b,11.5\nget b\nadd e,a,b\nsub g,a,b";
    handler(test);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I don't think the question as currently posed provides an MCVE

Comment: Mind explaining the difference between _s and _r?

Comment: @Mr_Pouet: its the same functions `_s` for Windows OS, `_r` for POSIX, only naming difference.